# Aggregate function inside Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am having some trouble with aggregate functions inside a `case` statement. I want to write a query that will set field A to `N` if it is equal to the minimum date of field A, or `M` otherwise.

Sample Code:

```
SELECT *, CASE
       WHEN Field_A = MIN(FIELD_A) THEN 'JN'
       ELSE 'JP'
       END AS JUDI

FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY *
```

I am not sure why the command runs but does not execute correctly. It labels all rows as `JN` in the `JUDI` Field. How can I fix this?

I am running SQL Server 7. What I want to achieve is that in a list of rows with different dates it labels those with the earliest date with `JN` and subsequent dates with `JP`.

Comment: You're grouping by `*`, which is the same as not grouping at all.

Comment: I suppose you could say `WHEN field_a = (SELECT MIN(field_a) FROM table_1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN t.Field_A = MIN(t.FIELD_A) OVER () THEN 'JN'
             ELSE 'JP'
        END) AS JUDI
FROM TABLE_1 t;
```

You don't need aggregation over the entire table for this.

Comment: OP said that he is using SQL Server 7. It definitely doesn't have window functions. On the other hand, I also find it difficult to believe that somebody is still using SQL Server 7 in 2017. @jwheeloc, if I'm not mistaken, you would need at least SQL Server 2005 to run the code in this answer.